# How to import go's mongo-driver bson

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go

I installed the mongo go driver with `go get go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/...`, but whenever I try to use `bson.EC` or `bson.NewDocument` as seen [here](https://github.com/compose-grandtour/golang/blob/master/example-mongodb-go-driver/example-mongodb.go), I get errors: `undefined: bson.NewDocument` and `undefined: bson.EC`. What am I missing here?

```
import (
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
)

func main() {
    // database and collection connection 
    // ...

    filter := bson.NewDocument(bson.EC.String("_id", "foo"))
    update := bson.NewDocument(
        bson.EC.SubDocumentFromElements(
            "$set",
            bson.EC.Double("pi", 3.14159),
        ),
    )
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking help with troubleshooting must include the code in question. Please update your question to include your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are the `bson` interfaces from older versions (before Beta version). You can construct the update operation as below example:

```
filter := bson.D{{"_id", "foo"}}
update := bson.D{{"$set", bson.D{{"pi", 3.14159}}}}
result, err := collection.UpdateOne(
    context.Background(),
    filter,
    update,
)
```

The snippet above is based on [MongoDB Go driver v1.0.0](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/releases/tag/v1.0.0)

For more example on how to use the driver please see:

- [MongoDB Go Driver Tutorial](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-go-driver-tutorial)
- [godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo)
- [godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson)